# Recreate "any()" function to find closest coordinates

Tags: python

I have this problem where I´m given to list of numbers each list for coordinate X and Y and I have to find which of the coordinates is closest to the first coordinate of the list, for that I have the following code:

```
import math

list1 = [1, 2, 1, 1]
list2 = [4, 7, 6, 3]

if len(list2) == len(list1):
    print ("number of elements does match\n")
else:
    print ("number of elements doesnt match\n")

a=1
dist_list = []

for i in range(1, len(list1)):
    x1 = list1[0]
    y1 = list2[0]

    x2 = list1[a]
    y2 = list2[a]

    dist = abs(math.sqrt((x1-(x2)**2) - (y1-(y2)**2)))
    a=a+1
    dist_list.append(dist)

print ("distancias:", dist_list, "\n")

for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return
    return False

print(list1[b],",",list2[b], "es la coordenada mas cercana")
#                            "is the closest coordinate"
```

In this case, the distances between coordinates show that that coordinate 1,3 is the closest to 1,4.

`distancias: [6.48074069840786, 5.656854249492381, 2.23606797749979]`

I need to say that here: `print(list1[b],",",list2[b], "es la coordenada mas cercana")`

I have been searching and found the `any()` function and according to Python documentation the way I can recreate the formula is:

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

But I can´t see how to recreate it for me to get the desired result. Also, I must say that for this exercise I can only use `for`, `in`, `while`,  sqer, abs and `append`.

Comment: you should rather use `min()`, not `any()` to find the closest.

Comment: Furas, I can't use min, my class hasn't see that yet so it's consider cheating

Comment: It looks like your source code has mixed tabs and spaces. You'll want to fix that, and make sure the indenting is correct. I see at least one indentation error. BTW Stack Overflow replaces tabs with four spaces.

Comment: `any()` is useless to find it - you should recreate `min()`. You can even see this in @steak_Overcooked answer.

Comment: Whichever teacher considers it "cheating" to learn things, I would like to have a word with them.

Comment: @René: Frankly what `any()` does is nothing like what a `find_closest()` function would do (since `any()` just returns `True` or `False`).

Comment: Please note that while it might work with this specific example, your formula for the distance is completely wrong...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`any()` is useless for this. You have to recreate `min()` (or maybe rather `numpy.argmin()`)

You have to get first distance at start and compare with all other values and when other value is smaller then keep value and its index.

```
b = 0   # get first index
b_value = dist_list[0]   # get first value

# compare with other distances
for i in range(1, len(dist_list)):
    if dist_list[i] < b_value:  # if new distance is smaller
        b = i  # keep new index
        b_value = dist_list[i]   # keep new value

b = b+1  # because `dist_list[0]` has value for `list1[1]`, not `list1[0]`
```

(BTW: normally I would use `enumerate()` instead of `range(len())` but I assume you don't know it)

---

**EDIT:** as @Tomerikoo pointed out formula for distance is wrong. It should be:

```
dist = math.sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)
```

---

Full code

```
import math

list1 = [1, 2, 1, 1]
list2 = [4, 7, 6, 3]

if len(list2) == len(list1):
    print ("number of elements does match\n")
else:
    print ("number of elements doesnt match\n")

dist_list = []

x1 = list1[0]
y1 = list2[0]

for i in range(1, len(list1)):

    x2 = list1[i]
    y2 = list2[i]

    #dist = abs(math.sqrt((x1-(x2)**2) - (y1-(y2)**2)))
    dist = math.sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)

    dist_list.append(dist)

print ("distancias:", dist_list, "\n")

b = 0
b_value = dist_list[0]

for i in range(1, len(dist_list)):
    if dist_list[i] < b_value:
        b = i
        b_value = dist_list[i]

b = b+1  # because `dist_list[0]` has value for `list1[1]`, not `list1[0]`

print(list1[b],",",list2[b], "es la coordenada mas cercana")
#                            "is the closest coordinate"
```

Comment: loop uses number `i` to get next value from list `dist_list[i]` and compare with element `b_value`. If next value is smaller then it assign to `b_value` and later it will compare with this new value. Simply use `print(i, dist_list[i], b_value, dist_list[i] < b_value)` to see values in variables

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm confused by the evaluation: for i in range(1, len(dist_list)): if dist_list[i] < b_value: I understand that i will take values from 1 to 3 until the condition dist_list < b_value is meet, but aren't we starting at the second value since in a list 0 = 1st, 1=2nd and so on? How do we handle the possibility of the fist distance to be the shortest? Or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: we start at second value but we get first value before loop to have value for comparition - `b_value = dist_list[0]`. If other values are longer then we will have `dist_list[0]` in `b_value` at the end. BTW: you do similar thing when you calculate distances - you get first value as `x1,y1` and later you start loop at second value and assign to `x2,y2`

Comment: ooooh so, if no value is smaller that the original [0] then that value by default is the smallest! Kk, I get it know, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun:

This could be easily done using a combination of [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```py
import math

list1 = [1, 2, 1, 1]
list2 = [4, 7, 6, 3]

ref_point = (list1[0], list2[0])
points = zip(list1[1:], list2[1:])

x,y = min(points, key=lambda point: (point[0]-ref_point[0])**2 + (point[1]-ref_point[1])**2)

print(x, ",", y, "es la coordenada mas cercana")
```

Note that `abs` is not really necessary because numbers to the power of 2 are always positive, and because we just care to compare, the `sqrt` is also not necessary (if `sqrt(x) > sqrt(y)` then also `x > y`).

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable that would stand for closest distance

```
import math

list1 = [1, 2, 1, 1]
list2 = [4, 7, 6, 3]

if len(list2) == len(list1):
    print ("number of elements does match\n")
else:
    print ("number of elements doesnt match\n")

dist_list = []
x1 = list1[0]
y1 = list2[0]
closest = 10000
closest_xy = 0
for i in range(1, len(list1)):
    x2 = list1[i]
    y2 = list2[i]
    dist = math.sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)
    if closest > dist:
        closest = dist
        closest_xy = i
    dist_list.append(dist)

print ("distancias:", dist_list, "\n")


print(list1[closest_xy],",",list2[closest_xy], "es la coordenada mas cercana")
#                            "is the closest coordinate"
```

Answer (score 0):

The math module has a [`hypot()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.hypot) function that would make doing what you need relatively easy:

```
import math


def find_closest(list1, list2):
    if len(list2) != len(list1):
        raise RuntimeError("number of elements does match")
    if len(list1) < 2:
        raise RuntimeError("the lists must contain at least two points")

    x0, y0 = list1[0], list2[0]
    index = 1
    min_dist = math.hypot(x0-list1[1], y0-list2[1]) # Distance between first and second pt.
    # See if any of the remaining pts are closer.
    for i in range(2, len(list1)):
        dist = math.hypot(x0-list1[i], y0-list2[i])
        if dist < min_dist:
            min_dist = dist
            index = i

    return (list1[i], list2[i])  # Closest point.


list1 = [1, 2, 1, 1]
list2 = [4, 7, 6, 3]

print(find_closest(list1, list2), "es la coordenada mas cercana")
```

Output:

```
(1, 3) es la coordenada mas cercana
```

If you can't use `math.hypot()`, it's fairly easy to write one of your own based on `math.sqrt()`:

```
def hypot(dx, dy):
    return math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do the square root to compare distances, just the sum of delta squares.  The min function can be used with its key parameter to get the smallest item in a list (or iterator) based on a computed value.  Using zip, you can combine the two lists into pairs of coordinates that will be more usable.  Zip is an iterator which is compatible with the min function:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 1, 1]
list2 = [4, 7, 6, 3]

points = zip(list1,list2)  # combine lists into (x,y) points
bx,by  = next(points)      # get the base point

# comparative distance calculation (square root not needed)
def distance(point): px,py = point; return (px-bx)**2+(py-by)**2

# minimum of remaining points based on distance calculation
px,py = min(points,key=distance)

print((px,py),"is nearest to",(bx,by))

# (1, 3) is nearest to (1, 4)
```

If you're looking for a solution without using min or zip, here's a simple loop based on iterators that will produce the desired result.  The iterators allow you to progress through both lists at the same time without using indexes (indexing is considered ugly in Python).

```
ix,iy    = iter(list1),iter(list2) # list iterators
bx,by    = next(ix),next(iy)       # base point
cx,cy,cd = None,None,None          # closest point and distance
for px in ix:
    py  = next(iy)                # progress through iterators
    dxy = (px-bx)**2+(py-by)**2   # compute comparative distance
    if cd is None or dxy < cd:
        cx,cy,cd = px,py,dxy      # keep first or closest found

print((px,py),"is nearest to",(bx,by))
```